# PHP mailer SMTP not working

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have configured the php.ini and sendmail.ini on in XAMPP to send emails and its working fine. Now when i change the code in php to use SMTP its not working... Its using the same host, same smtpsecure, same port, same email as in XAMPP and its not working...

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=testowemailer93@gmail.com
auth_password=1234
force_sender=testowemailer93@gmail.com
php.ini
[mail function]
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = testowemailer93@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"D:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
For Win32 only.
http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = testowemailer93@gmail.com
```

`and my php code`

```
<?php
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'testowemailer93@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '1234';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->setLanguage('pl', './vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/language/phpmailer.lang-pl.php');
$mail->setFrom("testowemailer93@gmail.com");
$mail->addAddress('xx.yyy@gmail.com');     // Add a recipient // Name is optional
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "Prośba o dostęp demo";
$mail->Body = "<p>Wysłano z formularza kontaktowego na stronie bhp.xyz.pl.</p>
</p>";
if(!$mail->Send()){
    echo "\n"."Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else{
    echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

> Errors: SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP f40sm329317edb.7 -
>   gsmtp CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO PhpStorm 2017.1 SERVER -> CLIENT:
>   501-5.5.4 HELO/EHLO argument "PhpStorm 2017.1" invalid, closing
>   connection.501 5.5.4 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=helo
>   f40sm329317edb.7 - gsmtp SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed: 501-5.5.4
>   HELO/EHLO argument "PhpStorm 2017.1" invalid, closing connection.501
>   5.5.4 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=helo f40sm329317edb.7 - gsmtp CLIENT -> SERVER: HELO PhpStorm 2017.1 SERVER -> CLIENT:  SMTP ERROR:
>   HELO command failed:  SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if
>   connected SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. SMTP connect()
>   failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
>   Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out... Too many hours spend on something like this..
I've added virtual host in XAMPP:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

 DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/BHP"
 ServerName bhpsmart.com
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
 SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
 <Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/BHP">
  Options All
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Require all granted
 </Directory>

 ErrorLog logs/platforma-error.log
 LogLevel info
 CustomLog logs/platforma.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

They key lines are :

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
```

Now its working properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is effectively a bug in PHPStorm, which I reported [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-35547).

There is an automatic workaround in the PHPMailer 6.0 branch, but you should be able to do it yourself by setting the `Hostname` property to something valid, for example:

```
$mail->Hostname = 'localhost.localdomain';
```

The `Hostname` property is the name presented in HELO/EHLO commands to the server(s) in the `Host` property - don't get the two confused!